# Расчет по (чему-либо)

Tags: предлоги, управление

Можно ли сказать "расчет по (чему-либо)?
Например, расчет по экономии энергии.

Comment: Экономия - это процесс или состояние, энергия - это общее понятие. А расчет ведут по чему-то конкретному, по конкретизированному объекту, поэтому предложение не полное: экономия энергии чего или какая энергия? Скажем, энергия электрическая, тогда расчет электричества, расчет экономии энергозатрат, расчет затрат электроэнергии. Экономия тут, честно говоря, лишний боком термин. Хотя экономить употребляют в разговорном стиле в смысле тратить меньше, но вообще экономить - это управлять/направлять, а не меньше/больше расходовать. Номить - это номос, обычай, обычай вести домашние дела

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что оба варианта возможны, например: (1) **Расчет экономии** от изменения используемых материалов и оптимизации технологического процесса. (2) **Расчет по экономии** светлых нефтепродуктов.

Выбор зависит **от ситуации.**

**(1) Расчет экономии**

Рассчитать экономию (В.п) или ***расчет экономии*** (Р.п) – **винительный** падеж (или родительный в отглагольном существительном) **прямо указывает** на предмет, это основное значение В.п. Речь идет о конкретном расчете (по каким-то заданным параметрам).

**(2) Расчет по экономии**

Основное значение **дательного падежа** с предлогом ПО – это указание **направления**. **Частное значение** предлога ПО можно посмотреть в словаре: 14. Употр. при обозначении области, сферы проявления действия, состояния и т.п. Занятие по английскому языку. **Исследование по физике.**

Соответственно, форма "***расчет по экономии***" – это не один конкретный расчет, а более **расширенные** сведения по расчету (возможно, с применением ряда примеров или с выводами и т.д.). Другими словами, это название больше подходит **для реферата**, а не для решения конкретной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

*Если сотрудник воспринимает зарплату в конце месяца как некую абстракцию, платить ему нужно каждую неделю или по факту выполнения задания.*

*По итогу Люксембургских соглашений Германия перевела 3 млрд марок Государству Израиль.*

(Примеры из нацкорпуса).

В вашем случае возможен *расчёт экономии* как некий план мероприятий, а также *расчёт по факту экономии.*